# The Fourth Lateran Council on Conscience

Tags: catholicism, reference-request, ecumenical-council, conscience, st-john-henry-newman

According to St. John Henry Newman (in his essay on Conscience):

[image]

However, [*Papal Encyclicals Online*](https://www.papalencyclicals.net/councils/ecum12-2.htm#25), says nothing of the sort. Unlike previous Councils, the proceedings were not formally recorded. Hence, we must rely on other sources which provide accounts from observers of the Council.

Question: Can someone produce evidence that the Fourth Lateran Council promulgated what Newman indicates on conscience?

Comment: you may have uncovered an urban legend created by a Saint.

Comment: @DanFefferman After searching the quote in Latin for a while, wow, **so many** books, not to mention articles, quote this [Section 5 of Newman's Letter to the Duke of Norfolk](https://www.newmanreader.org/works/anglicans/volume2/gladstone/section5.html), indicating how viral a misquote could be even before the age of Internet !  I only find 1-2 matches in a book that has that exact quote, but not attributing it to Newman / Fourth Lateran Council.  [One book (in Latin) introduces it as an axiom (page 192)](https://archive.org/details/summatheologiaem0001merk/page/192/mode/2up).

Comment: Another, from *Compendium theologicae veritatis*, a medieval theological digest compiled c. 1260-1270 by a Dominican theologian [Hugh Ripelin of Strasbourgh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hugh_Ripelin_of_Strasburg), [Book V Chapter 59](https://catholiclibrary.org/library/view?docId=/Medieval-OR/HughofStrasbourgCompendiumTheologicaeInSeptemLibrosDigestum.00000229.la.html&chunk.id=00000443) attributes it to St. Augustine.

Comment: Looking closely at the punctuation, Cardinal Newman is quoting Cardinal Gousset. It is Cardinal Gousset who ascribes the quote to the Fourth Lateran Council. Gousset was a French academic who studied councils, amongst other things, so it seems not unreasonable for Newman to quote him quoting the Council. Gousset may have misascribed the statement to the Council as a typo,  or he may, with reasons, have ascribed it to the Council, elsewhere in his works. If it was originally from St Augustine it seems odd neither Gousset nor Newman recognised it, but they were very busy men, I suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are to trust the *Compendium theologicae veritatis*, a medieval theological digest compiled c. 1260-1270 by a Dominican theologian [Hugh Ripelin of Strasbourgh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hugh_Ripelin_of_Strasburg), in [Book V, Chapter 59](https://catholiclibrary.org/library/view?docId=/Medieval-OR/HughofStrasbourgCompendiumTheologicaeInSeptemLibrosDigestum.00000229.la.html&chunk.id=00000443), the quote is **attributed to St. Augustine** (!!):

> Hoc dico secundum formam tradendi, non secundum virtutem intelligendi, quia omnia praecepta negativa marium et animum ligant. Mullis modis ligamur, scilicet lege naturae, ut est diligere Deum super om- nia, et nulli facere quod nobis fieri nolumus . Praeceptis divinis, ut ligabatur Adam praeceptis sibi datis , et Judaei suis . Voto, quia secundum Augustinum, vovere est voluntatis, sed reddere est necessitatis . Unde quibusdam etiam consilia sunt praecepta, sicut religiosis qui voverunt talia. Decretis patrum, ut est jejunare aliquas vigilias, et hujusmodi. Consuetudine, secundum quod in Francia primogenitus succedit in regno. Mandatis praelatorum. Unde : Super cathedram Moysi, etc, . **Conscientia, quia secundum Augustinum, " Quidquid " fit contra conscientiam, aedificat ad " gehennam. "**

Google translate:

> I say this according to the form of delivery, not according to the power of understanding, because all the negative precepts bind the sea and the mind. We are bound in many ways, namely by the law of nature, such as to love God above all things, and to do to no one what we do not wish to be done to us. By the divine precepts, as Adam was bound by the precepts given to himself, and to his Jews. I wish, because according to Augustine, to vow is of the will, but to repay is of necessity. Wherefore to some also counsels are precepts, as to the religious who make such vows. The decrees of the fathers, as it is to fast certain vigils, and the like. According to custom, according to which in France the eldest son succeeds to the kingdom. Orders of the superiors. Whence: Upon the seat of Moses, etc. **[Conscience], because according to Augustine, "whatever" is done against conscience, builds up to "hell."**

The compendium is only a few decades after the Fourth Lateran Council (1215).
It's reasonable to propose that **EVEN IF** the quote is part of the unrecorded proceedings (we may try to search it in an ["extensive eyewitness account" whose manuscript was published in 1964](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourth_Council_of_the_Lateran#Records)), maybe the proceeding *itself* was referencing St. Augustine.

Two follow-up research that can improve this answer:

1. Study the 1964 paper [*A New Eyewitness Account of the Fourth Lateran Council*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/27830771) reporting the discovery (1962) of MS 1105 (The Giessen Manuscript) housed at the library of the University of Giessen.  The paper contains the Latin text plus commentary, but I'm not sure whether it is complete.  Since it was newly discovered, it's doubtful that Cardinal Newman himself found the quote there.
2. The paper above mentions other possible records (some survived, some don't) of the council (page 122-123), such as the Chronicle of Richard of San Germano, "in the long recension" published by Gaudenzi (1888) and Garufi (1936-38), thus may not also be available to Cardinal Newman as he wrote the [Letter to the Duke of Norfolk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_to_the_Duke_of_Norfolk) in 1875.  But who knows he had an advance copy or a previous edition.
3. Try to locate this quote in the works of St. Augustine.

Comment: Thank you kindly for this answer.